# Formatter not called despite passing the same binding path

Tags: odata, sapui5

I can't wrap my head around this. What am I overlooking?

Here is a minimal sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/VjqGeG9JpHblyLBb?preview

> ```xml
> <tnt:InfoLabel
>  text="{
>    path: 'LastName',
>    formatter: '.formatter.typeText'
>  }" 
>  colorScheme="{
>    path: 'LastName',
>    formatter: '.formatter.typeColor'
>  }" />
> ```
>
> ```js
> // formatter.js
> sap.ui.define([], function () {
>  "use strict";
>  return {
>    typeText: function(sLastName) {
>      // Called with 'sLastName' value
>    },
>    typeColor: function(sLastName) {
>      // Not called
>    }
>  };
> });
> ```

I'm using UI5 1.79 with `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **`targetType: 'any'`** to the property binding info that has the issue. E.g.:

```xml
<tnt:InfoLabel
  text="{
    path: 'LastName',
    formatter: '.getMyText'
  }"
  colorScheme="{
    path: 'LastName',
    formatter: '.getMyColorScheme',
    targetType: 'any'
  }"
/>
```

With `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`, [*data types*](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/blob/ef962968e1e2d86f4b2b39ac4091d9263cf683e3/docs/Formatting%2C_Parsing%2C_and_Validating_Data_07e4b92.md#data-types) in property bindings are automatically determined according to the EDM type of the entity property. I.e. in the case above: even without having a certain `type` explicitly assigned to the `text` property, the `v4.ODataPropertyBinding` automatically picks the [`String` type](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.String) (because `LastName` has `Type="Edm.String"` in $metadata) and assigns it to the `type`:

```
<tnt:InfoLabel
  text="{
    path: 'LastName',
    formatter: '.getMyText',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' <-- automatically added by v4.ODataPropertyBinding
  }"
```

This was fine for the `text` property since it actually awaits a *string* value, but doing the same for other properties, such as `colorScheme` which awaits an *int* value, results in a FormatException.*

In order to prevent the automatic [Type Determination](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/53cdd55a77ce4f33a14bd0767a293063), the `targetType: 'any'` has to be added.

---

* With [commit:`4611772`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/46117728baa48160da7bb2b9be289fd0a7f5e8b9), which is available as of 1.80, we can see the corresponding error message in the console:

> FormatException in property 'colorScheme' of 'Element sap.tnt.InfoLabel#...': *<LastName value>* is not a valid int value. **Hint:** single properties referenced in composite bindings and within binding expressions are automatically converted into the type of the bound control property, unless a different 'targetType' is specified. targetType:'any' may avoid the conversion and lead to the expected behavior.